# Does Eric Flint plan for his 1632 (Ring of Fire) effect to last?

Tags: 1632-ring-of-fire, assiti-shards

Does Flint indicate that the effect of dropping Grantville into 1632 is permanent (meaning the parallel Universe created this way will last, and not disappear in a short time like a burst soap bubble in some quantum fluctuation; or because the Assiti Shard that created it stopped "working")?

I'm interested specifically in something mentioned in the books, or his forums by him.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about real "permanence", but the effect within canon clearly lasted **at least** for 300 years, till late 1900s.

In "Ring of Fire III" anthology; David Carrico's "The Sound of Sweet Strings" novel(ette?) has a Coda section, which quotes a **1979** "in-universe" Oxford University Press publication *"From the Fall of The Fire: The Coming of Grantville and the Music of Europe"* that mentions Grantville's contribution to music.

The anthology was edited by Eric Flint; and thus completely canonically approved by him in every detail.

---

As a side note, the actual effect of Assiti Shards may be more fully discussed in "[Time Spike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assiti_Shards_series#Time_Spike)" series co-authored with Kosmatka.

---

Also, it should be noted that Fta Tei (side branch of humans in the far future) exterminated Assiti for "endangering time and space" with their "art". While it's not a certain conclusion, I wouldn't expect something with temporary "soap bubble" effect to be on the level of "endangering time and space" warranting an extermination of an entire race 85 million years after Ring of Fire events.